# SharePoint 2013 dynamic Navigation for Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, custom, branding

I am building a site in SP 2013 and have a question on the navigation.
Initially we will have 4 items in the global navigation as: 
Page 1 Page 2 Page 3 Page 4 
Now, based on the user selection, I will modify the navigation and show it like this, suppose
If a user goes into a section of Page 1: 
Page 1 **Section 1** Page 2 Page 3 Page 4 
If a user goes into a section of Page 2: 
Page 1 Page 2 **section 2** Page 3 Page 4 
How can I acheive something like this?
Should I show them as a term and then show/hide them based on the selected section?

Comment: Any help here ?

Comment: Each term has GUIDs of the parent terms it is placed under. Can you use this information for your task?

Comment: Hi @ oldbam, Thanks for your reply. I need to achieve this programmatically can you help there ?